# Grouping Zip Codes by Region in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 50000 something random entries in a worksheet categorized by Zip Code and I need to group them by Zones.  I have a reference list that shows which Zip corresponds to which Zone.  How can I add a column to the worksheet with the Zone that corresponds to the Zip without manually looking it up and typing it in.

This is what the reference list looks like:

Zone Zip

1    03227

1    03254

1    03269
...

2    05687

2    05691

etc

Comment: Review the Excel Functions `match, vlookup, or HLookup`.  One of them will do what you're trying to do.

Comment: if you can flip the zipcode and the zone, you could use a vloopup formula.  If you don't want to change your lookup table, you could use a combination of index and match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using VLookup

[image]